# My screen shows "ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS usertty2, user login(here I can type ) when I press enter it shows PASSWORD: (I cannot type anything here)

Tags: authentication, passwords, space, restart, reboot

I cannot restart my laptop. Before rebooting my harddisk was full I don't know if this caused the problem. Now I can see a blankscreen and an underscore where I cannot type anything(automatically erased), when I entered alt+F2 "user login:" option came I entered my username next it showed "PASSWORD:" i cannot type here.. what should I do to start my laptop and fyi my laptop only have ubuntu(no windows)

I tried reboot by pressing power off button for a long time. I saw so many suggestions but I couldn't do anything because I cannot type in the blank screen

Comment: fyi this is the wrong site, as Stack Overflow is specifically for *programming* q&a. General computing questions belong on [su] - just be sure to read the guidelines there first.

Comment: Also, please be mindful of tagging. None of these tags really represent the issue (and some of the tag descriptions even say not to use the tags, such as [tag:space])